# collapsible accordion return to active status

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-tabs

Need help guys im new to javascript, how can i make the status of collapsed icon to "+" again when i click the current tab to collapsed? my problem is the "-" current tab has that sign whenever i close the tab again, here's the code and the sample link: http://www.dev.redefinegraphicstudio.com/acp/SLOCPI%20Mobile/HOMEPAGE.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.expand-collapse-menu > li > a').on('click', function(){
    var $this =  $(this);
    if($this.parent().hasClass('current')){
        $this.parent().parent().find('ul').stop().slideUp();
    }else{
        $this.parent().parent().find('li').each(function(){ $(this).removeClass('active'); })
        $this.parent().parent().find('ul').stop().slideUp();
        $this.parent().toggleClass('active');
        $this.parent().find('ul').stop().slideToggle(500);
    }
});

$(".tabs-menu").find('li').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('current')){
        var tab = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
         $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
         $(tab).fadeIn();
    }
});

$(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
});


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your first function, when you change it to

```
 $('.expand-collapse-menu > li > a').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.parent().hasClass('active')) {  // change to active instead of current
        $this.parent().toggleClass('active');  // add this line
        $this.parent().parent().find('ul').stop().slideUp();
    } else {
        $this.parent().parent().find('li').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $this.parent().parent().find('ul').stop().slideUp();
        $this.parent().toggleClass('active');
        $this.parent().find('ul').stop().slideToggle(500);
    }
});
```

the class `active` that sets the background color to orange and the minus sign as background image will also be toggled for the active element. You could also remove the `$this.parent().toggleClass('active');` from the `if` and `else` clauses and set it below as it should be toggled anyway.

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to keep changing the class of the clicked element in the `if` and `else` clauses, you can also consider to use `addClass("active")` and `removeClass("active")` instead of `toggleClass("active")` as it's known if the class should be added or removed.

I've set up a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97g49fz5/) with the relevant part from your page.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to use ``$this.parent().parent().find('li').removeClass('active');``?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for considering. Sure, and then to `addClass("active")` in the `else` - I just made up this example to show why it didn't work / where the toggle is missing and also mentioned that the `toggleClass()` could be moved below the if/else as it has to be toggled for both cases.

Comment: thanks mathias! ive seen what you did there and perfect explanation! thanks!

Comment: @rgs Glad I was able to help you. If this answered your question, you can consider to accept this answer so the question will be marked as closed / solved. In case you don't know how this works and why, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235